# I get error when add dataset in Microsoft Report

Tags: rdlc

I have rdlc report when  I add new dataset I got this error

```html
Could not load file or assembly 'BasicFrame.WebControls.BasicDatePicker, Version=1.4.0.25598, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e1cce521aa9b4849' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

What does it mean ?

Comment: The project you're getting the dataset from must have a reference to a library called `BasicFrame.WebControls.BasicDatePicker` that couldn't be found. This type of error usually appears when building a project and one of the dependencies is corrupt. I suggest you try and remove this reference and rebuild the project, if you're still getting an error, try and add it again but make sure it's assigned to the correct dll.

Answer (score 0):

In one case The problem may be

> namespace that Used in   "BasicFrame.WebControls.BasicDatePicker" dll,

You must add namespaces that used in "BasicFrame.WebControls.BasicDatePicker" dll project, To Config File Of your main project

like this:

```
 <namespaces>
    <add namespace="AceComponent.Views.Helpers"/>
  </namespaces>
```